# How to prevent selected users from using "newgrp" with a password

Tags: security, group, account-restrictions

I'd like to know how can I avoid add some users to a group?
I need to avoid some users join to a group --I want to lock a group from some users, not all.

Details

```
lgroupmod -L dba ==> This prevents users from using the group password and    
gpasswd -R dba ==> is restriction to a group
```

I need to lock a group for some users *not* for all group' members.

Comment: user can't join group on their own, only root can add user to group. may be you don't want Alice user not able to see file belonging to bob group ? that's a different problem.

Comment: It's very hard to make sense of your question. Could you try clarifying a bit, perhaps with a no-real-names-please example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ok thanks, this is an example. I have the group dba but I need that two users cannot add to that group. (The group appear lock for them)

Comment: As Archemar already wrote: The users can't add themselves to a group. I don't understand the question, either.

Comment: Off course!, you are wrong (look the command newgrp).  Let me explain with more details.  # lgroupmod -L dba ==> This prevents users from using the  group  password and #gpasswd -R dba ==> is restriction to a group but I need to do it only for some users!!

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. Which os do you use btw?

Comment: Ok, no problem, I used Rhel 6/7 or Centos

Comment: newgrp command fork a new shell for actual user *among predefined group*, you may even add a passwd in /etc/group (though I have never seen it used).

Comment: I need to lock a group for some users, not all group (I do it actually).

Comment: Users can only use `newgrp` to gain access to group identity *if* you define a password for the group.  Don't define a password ( the usual state of affairs ) and only those users you explicitly add to the group can be members.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using the wrong tool for the job. Passwords for groups are a rarely-used feature; most of the times, you assign each user to whatever groups you want, and they get group privileges when they log in, without having to do anything special.

If you want users to have to take some action when they want to use group privileges, for example for logging purposes, or to make it clear that they should only use group privileges in special circumstances, the most obvious way would be to use [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo). For users who should have access to the group, run `visudo` to add a rule in the `sudoers` file like

```
alice ALL = (:dba) ALL
```

and tell users to run `sudo -g dba somecommand` rather than `echo 'somecommand' | newgrp dba`.

If you have a highly unusual scenario where you really need users to type a shared password to gain access to the group, yet you only want certain users to have access to the group, you can still leverage `newgrp`. The idea is to restrict it to certain users. Leverage `newgrp` rather than writing your own because elevating privileges securely is tricky. Linux's `newgrp` doesn't use PAM, probably because basically nobody uses `newgrp`. So get the source code of the version on your distribution, and modify it to read a file `/etc/gshadow.dba`. The point of reading a different file is to avoid other avenues of increasing group privileges such as `sg`. Add a line with the `dba` group and its password to `/etc/gshadow.dba`, not `/etc/gshadow`. Compile the modified `newgrp`, install it to `/usr/local/bin/newgrp-dba`, and set its permissions such that only certain users can execute it:

```
chmod u=srwx,go= /usr/local/bin/newgrp-dba
setfacl -m user:alice:x /usr/local/bin/newgrp-dba
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a password to `/etc/group` or `/etc/gshadow`. Format is similar to `/etc/passwd`, except that the number of fields differs. You still need to put the password in the second field, though.

Comment: I need to lock a group for some users, not all group (I do that actually with gpasswd and $newgrp and its password but some user tell to them the password and they appear in the group). Thanks for your time but I don't need to lock the group, I need to do to some users.

Comment: That isn't possible. Group passwords are an all-or-nothing approach.

Comment: Hello everyone, finally I have got the great answer. Sadly, in Other distributions the solution is #man timeout but in rhel this isn't exist. The file /etc/pam.d/time.conf use range-time for specific services and ttys by users and groups but that time is like a time to permit a service, so the correct way is to apply acl to the command newgrp for those specific users and they cannot add to dba group hahahaha. Thank you all for help me.